# How to show CircularProgressIndicator for 3 seconds in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, load

is it possible to wrap my CircularProgressIndicator using Timer... I want to show my CircularProgressIndicator for 3 seconds, but I don't know how to do it... most of resource that I have read is wrapping a function that consist of CircularProgressIndicator inside Timer.. here is my code

```
Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String dataIn = prefs.getString("clockin");
    return dataIn;
  }

Widget defaultClock() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.hasData) {
          return Text(snap.data);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in using [Future.delayed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html).

Following minimal code explain more clearly.

```
 String data;
  Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String dataIn = prefs.getString("clockin") ?? 'default';
    return dataIn;
  }

  callme() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    getData().then((value) => {
          setState(() {
            data = value;
          })
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callme();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: data == null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text(data),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I am new in flutter dart... would you like to give me a little explanation about what is this mean ```prefs.getString("clockin") ?? 'default';```

Comment: it mean's that if you did not set any value of clockin in sharedpreferences then it will take default value which i assign after ??. ?? is know as null aware operator.

Comment: by using your code... I will not need my Widget ```defaultClock()``` anymore...am I right, if I say like that?

Comment: yes you can directly do showcase your data  as i did.

Comment: wait,I will let you know the result after I run it in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
  Timer _timer;
  int _start = 3;
  bool loading = true;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_start < 1) {
            setState(() {
              loading = false;
            });
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
     void initState() {
       startTimer();
       super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
}


Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String dataIn = prefs.getString("clockin");
    return dataIn;
  }

Widget defaultClock() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.hasData && loading == false ) {
          return Text(snap.data);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps,

You can use the Timer widget.

On load show the CircularProgessIndicator and at the end you can call the function that you need after 10 seconds have passed.

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 10, callback));
```